# Why does an analog oscilloscope have a frequency number written on it?

Tags: oscilloscope

So in our lab, we are working with an oscilloscope, an Analog to be precise. It is the Tektronix 2205. My question is if it is analog, then why would it have "20 MHz" written on its box.

Comment: I hope you didn't expect infinite frequency. Without reading tf manual, i can say that scope is specified (meant to work) and rated (tested and found working) under certain conditions. That doesn't mean that it will not work for 25mhz. Maybe the signal will be distorted or maybe not. It's important you don't count on accurate measurement outside scope's range.

Comment: 20 MHz is the upper limit of the bandwidth the scope can display without significant attenuation. The concept to understand, if you take to a search engine, is "analog bandwidth." If you feed a 50 MHz sine wave into that scope, it will be greatly attenuated.

Comment: So to make it simple, that means that as long as I play around with a frequency below 20 MHz, everything is fine, right

Comment: Not quite, a 1Hz square wave will have components of way higher bandwidth. 20MHz means it will have a given loss at 20MHz sinewave. So you will probably be fine measuring a sine wave of 21MHz for example, it will just probably be lower amplitude. At such frequencies probing will also make quite a difference on what you see on the scope.

Comment: Very importantly, the scope should be able to trigger on a 20MHz input of suitable deflection on the screen (perhaps 1 division) or of suitable VPP into the EXT TRIG connector.

Comment: If you display a signal with 10 MHz, you don't get much information about its shape. A good square wave signal would not be displayed as such because the harmonics at 20, 30, 40, 50 MHz will be substantially reduced in amplitude. Only a 10 MHz sine wave will keep its shape, but not a triangle, ramp or any other non sinusodial periodic signal.

Comment: Those MHz they convert in k$ or k€.

Comment: 2205 was a model and 20MHz was the base with -30 option (MHz ) upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being an analog scope the signal is limited by the BW of the amplifier of this unit to 20MHz.

This in turn implies it's minimum rise time from 10 % to 90 % defined as approx 0.35/BW or 17.5ns according to manual.

This is often defined by the -3dB bandwidth for a low pass filter. The attenuation slope beyond this is undefined but is expected to be -6dB per octave per "order" of RC filter equivalent circuit so it may drop off as a 1st order then higher orders from cascaded stages.

Since this scope was produced in the 80's to meet the low cost market, the power required and cost of components at that time, dictated these limits. (the most expensive part being the CRT BW)

If you have a higher BW (e.g.200MHz) scope , it will probably have a 20MHz filter button for improving measurements with unwanted RF noise .

The important parameter to remember is that although old CRT displays had pixel BW up to 250MHz this was only from pixel to pixel and not 90% of the vertical rise.  The cost of making these high voltage fast slew rate amplifiers and tubes dictated the overall cost.  Now with DSO's the BW is increased cheaper with results that can use  a low cost LCD.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the single most important parameter that tells you whether a particular scope is suitable for a particular job is its analog bandwidth. Signals that fall within this bandwidth will be displayed properly, while signals that exceed this bandwidth (even if just in their harmonics) will be distorted.

Since the bandwidth of (nearly) all scopes extends to DC, the important parameter is the upper frequency limit, and this is the number that is printed on the scope. This is the frequency at which the height of a sinewave display is reduced by 3 dB, or to about 70% of its nominal (low-frequency) value.